# IIS 6.1: ASP Script Timeout Parameter

Tags: iis, asp-classic, timeout

I'm using IIS 6.1 to configure a web server to upload files to. I get the following error when trying to upload files over 25 MB:

The maximum amount of time for a script to execute was exceeded. You can change this limit by changing the value in the IIS Administration tools.

I've tried following the instructions here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/268364

But there is no properties menu in the version I am using.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://share-useful-links-here.blogspot.com/2011/02/asp-script-time-out.html

Found the answer here.

Click the ASP Tab --> Expand "Limit Properties" --> Set "Script Time-out" parameter to what you want

Answer (score 6):

Why involve the entire server's script time out property for one single page?

Just goto the page that times out and add this at the top'

```
Server.ScriptTimeout=200 'now you will get 200 seconds for the script to its processing
```

and your IIS is not touched.

that's the way the go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Metabase Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17275) to edit this [property on IIS 6](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/4cf723ef-2758-476e-8947-d4fc3a88b0f1.mspx?mfr=true).